# asp.net - problems getting dropdownlist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using a code behind function to bind my dropdownlist dynamically, when a user changes the dropdownlist and submit a purchase, the selectedvalue is always empty.

I have tried both ddl.SelectedItem.ToString(); and ddl.SelectedValue.ToString(); but none work. Also for these 2 code behind functions below, I can't seem to use void methods instead of a function that needs a returning value and a parameter, is there anyway to use void methods without parameters? Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<%# FormattedSize((string)Eval("Size")) %>
<%# FormattedGetSize((string)Eval("Size")) %>
```

**inline:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnDataBinding='<%# FormattedSize((string)Eval("Size")) %>'></asp:DropDownList>

<a href='AddToCart.aspx?CategoryId=<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>&&ProductId=<%# Eval("ProductId" ) %>&&Size=<%# FormattedGetSize((string)Eval("Size")) %>' style="border: 0 none white;">
```

**Code Behind:**

```
   protected string FormattedSize(string size)
    {
        if (size.Contains("s"))
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            ddl.Items.Add("S");
        }

    if (size.Contains("m"))
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
        ddl.Items.Add("M");
    }

    if (size.Contains("f"))
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
        ddl.Items.Add("Freesize");
    }
    return null;
}

protected string FormattedGetSize(String Size)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
    string selectedSize = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
    return selectedSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work is because.. "you're doing it wrong". You're expecting that the `<a href=..` will change based on the user interaction but instead it is already generated when user receives the page. If you want the link to change based on the dropdown, you'd have to have either:

1. a postback on dropdown selection, then the link would change...
2. you could change the `href` with some javascript by attaching event on dropdown selection

Comment: Hi, I set the AutoPostBack of the ddl to true but it didn't work. Any advice?

Comment: Yes. Wherever it is that you assign data to the dropdownlist, do it only `if(!IsPostBack)` , cause otherwise whatever it is you have in viewstate is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

What you do in your Page_Load method? Do you check to see if the current request is a post back or not (using IsPostBack)?
If so, check for IsPostBack and bind your DropDownList to the underlying data source only on Get requests.